# regex to remove every hyphen except between two words

Tags: python, regex

I am cleaning a text and I would like to remove all the hyphens and special characters. Except for the hyphens between two words such as: `tic-tacs`, `popcorn-flavoured`.

I wrote the below regex but it removes every hyphen.

```
text='popcorn-flavoured---'
new_text=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '',text)
new_text
```

I would like the output to be:

`popcorn-flavoured`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace matches of the regular expression

```
-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-
```

with empty strings.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aTrJAS/3/) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\_(ツ)_/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python demo](http://tpcg.io/hlbJrRjX)

The regex will match hyphens that are not both preceded and followed by a word character.

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
-        match '-'
(?!\w)   the previous character is not a word character
|
(?<!\w)  the following character is not a word character
-        match '-'
```

`(?!\w)` is a *negative lookahead*; `(?<!\w)` is a *negative lookbehind*.

Comment: Thank you Cary. Is there a way to include the removal of special characters into this regex?  For example: if the string was 'popcorn-flavour@ed--$-'

Comment: Just change `-` to the *character class* `[-$'_]` that contains the characters you wish to remove.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, you could capture a hyphen between word characters and keep that group in the replacement. Using an alternation, you could match the hyphens that you want to remove.

```
(\w+-\w+)|-+
```

*Explanation*

- `(\w+-\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word chars, hyphen and 1+ word chars
- `|` Or
- `-+` Match 1+ times a hyphen

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ofqtr4/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jIjamF)

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"(\w+-\w+)|-+"
test_str = ("popcorn-flavoured---\n"
    "tic-tacs")

result = re.sub(regex, r"\1", test_str)
print (result)
```

*Output*

```
popcorn-flavoured
tic-tacs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findall()` to get that part that matches your criteria.

```
new_text = re.findall('[\w]+[-]?[\w]+', text)[0]
```

Play around with it with other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
p = re.compile(r"(\b[-]\b)|[-]")
result = p.sub(lambda m: (m.group(1) if m.group(1) else ""), text)
```

**Test**

With:

```
text='popcorn-flavoured---'
```

Output (result):

```
popcorn-flavoured
```

**Explanation**

This pattern detects hyphens between two words:

```
(\b[-]\b)
```

This pattern detects all hyphens

```
[-]
```

Regex substitution

```
p.sub(lambda m: (m.group(1) if m.group(1) else " "), text)
```

When hyphen detected between two words m.group(1) exists, so we maintain things as they are

```
else "")
```

Occurs when the pattern was triggered by [-] then we substitute a "" for the hyphen removing it.